# I am getting the error "expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token"?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

    int i, F(int);
    int F((int - 1) + (int - 2))
    {
        return (int - 1) + (int - 2)
    }
    for(i=1; i<=15; i++)
    {
        F(1) == 0;
        F(i) == F(i-1)+F(i-2);
        printf("F(%d) = %d", i, F(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to print the fibonacci sequence from the first to the fifteenth number

Comment: `int F((int - 1) + (int - 2))` -- What is this supposed to imply?

Comment: You do know that you can't have nested function in C?

Comment: Whenever you're posting compiler error / warning messages, always indicate the *exact line* that the message refers to.

Comment: Moreover, you don't use `==` for __assignment__.

Comment: Also, `F(1) == 0;` calls `F(1)` and compares it with zero, but then discards the result.

Comment: Looks like someone's trying to switch to C from a functional programming language.

Comment: All in all I think you need to do something more basic first before trying this.

Comment: Suggest that you read a basic tutorial to begin with.

Comment: You cannot declare a function and a variable on same statement. Functions have default storage type of `extern` while variables have `auto` (Local Variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int F(int n){
    if(n==1)
        return 0;
    if(n==2)
        return 1;
    return F(n - 1) + F(n - 2);
}

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=15; i++){
        printf("F(%d) = %d\n", i, F(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: HI thanks for the correction. I'm fairly new to programming and i would just like to ask a couple questions if you don't mind.
First: Do the functions always have to be defined before the main functions?

Second: What purpose does the n serve in F(int n)?
And also, why did you not use else before return F(n - 1) + F(n - 2)?
Thanks again!

Comment: @user3580389 (1) You must be defined before it can be used to function. However, you can be defined later by placing the prototype declaration. E.g `int F(int n); int main(){ F(4);//call ... } int F(int n) { ... }`

Comment: @user3580389 (2) `F(int n)` : It can be used in the body of the function it defines the variables as parameters. It can be used as a function that is already defined when calling recursive functions.